# Problems with retrofit2 calls format

Tags: android, api, rest, retrofit2

I am experiencing some issues with a retrofit call to the backend. I explain you the situation:

I have developed the API call in the postman by the next way:

[image]

In the Android studio I try to do the API call by the next way:

```
 @GET("restricted/GaiakIkuskatzea")
    Call<Gaiak> getGaiak(@Query("grupo") String grupo);
```

But what I get is a empty object of JSON type, as I got if in the postman I make an api call without the param I showed before, and with the parameter specifyed in the body:

[image]

Does any of you know why I am having porblems with the Studio?

Thanks!

Comment: do you add "BackEnd10P/rest/school" in your url?

Comment: yes, the solution was a different fact related with the name you receive the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer was watching the name that recived the data that you were receiving, in my case I put http and observed the mistake.